# Data not showing after ibase_fetch_object from Firebird database

Tags: php, firebird, crud

I'm new to CRUD with PHP (OOP). I've successfully to inserted the data, but after I insert the data, all the list of data in the data is not showing. Here is the code:

**Function.php**

```
 class Section {
     function showSection(){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM section";
        $query=ibase_query($sql);
        return $query;
        }
   }
```

**List.php**

```
<table>
   <tr>
   <td>No</td>
   <td>Section Code</td>
   <td>Section Name</td>
   </tr>
        <?php
        include ('Function.php');
        $No=1;
        $Sec=new Section();
        $show=$Sec->showSection();
        while ($data=ibase_fetch_object($show)){
        echo"
        <tr>
        <td>
        <td>$data->section_code</td>
        <td>$data->section_name</td>
        </tr>";
        $No++
        };        
        ?>
        </table>
```

[image: Data not showing]
What should I do? Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$data->SECTION_CODE` (field name in uppercase)